# ios7 UILabel font styling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to create a labels with iOS7 default font and styling.

For instance, I'm trying to create a view similar to the notification center. I did been able to get a snap of the screen using the new snapshot API but I can't match my label to iOS styling.

This is the style that I wish to achieve:
[image: Notification center label]

My code up to now is:

```
_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[_titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]
                                           size:32.0f]];
_titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;

[_titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[_titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[_titleLabel setText:self.title];
[self.view addSubview:_titleLabel];
```

Currently I'm getting a bold text which doesn't match the nice looking of the new style.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Try a different font. Try AppleSDGothicNeo-Light. Try every font there is. Whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of the new font styles in iOS7, make sure you look at all of the available options: [Text Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Text_Styles)

In this case, you're using the subheadline, which has a specific style. You should choose the style based upon the kind of text you are displaying. In this case, subheadlines are bold, while body text is not. It's also important to note that the font styles will be different based upon the user's Accessibility settings for fonts. A user can change the dynamic type option or bold text option.

Since you're setting the font size specifically, you should probably avoid using font descriptors, and just use the font you want. If you just want to use the standard iOS font with size variations, your best bet is to use `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32.0f]`. This will give you the standard system font at whatever size you like.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Your answer solved another question that I had and didn't asked yet - how to allow dynamic font based on the user accessibility settings, Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different font?

```
[_titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32.0f]];
```